# How to track only browser window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jquery UI dialog, and I want to resize dialog relative to `window` height and width, but when I use `$(window).resize()` or `$(window).on('resize')` they both track modals resize too. So when my `$(window).resize()` updates dialogs height width, modal triggers resize, thus firing another resize on itself.

**How can I limit $(window).resize() only to browser window resize?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow down only to actual browser window re-size:

```
var onBrowserReszie = function(e){
    if(e.target === window){
     // Do something here spcific to browser window resize   
    }
}

$(window).on("resize",onBrowserReszie)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//...

var isBrowserResize = true;

//...

function preventWindowResizeEvent() {
    isBrowserResize = false;
}

//...

$(window).resize(function() {
    if (isBrowserResize) {
        //...
    } else {
        isBrowserResize = true;
    }
});
```

and you call `preventWindowResizeEvent` from any `resize` where you do not want to run the event for the main window `resize`.

Comment: How could I implement this idea without altering any of my existing code and e.g., jqeury UI dialog resize? This is a solution but very vague...

Comment: You need to implement this, so it is impossible to not change your code. I think you could do something like this: $("*").resize(function(){if ($(this) !== $(window)) preventWindowResizeEvent();}); Note that I did not test this and I do not know whether it works, so I did not add it to my answer, but I think it is worth a try. If it works, then let me know, so I will edit my answer to add this function so people in the future will easily solve this problem.

Comment: `$(window).on("resize",function(e){
if(e.target===window)console.log("window")
});` This seems to work and only will fire if caller element is window, so there will be no circular function calls. '$("*").resize()` is bad practice imo.